# Swift checksum of bytes

Tags: arrays, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, checksum

I have a quite tricky problem. I send an array of bytes with an iOS device to a ble device (led light) which works just fine.
I have a document for all commands which is very poorly translated from chinese.
The whole byte-package is build like this:

- The front of command ( 1 byte )
- The length of command packet ( 1 byte )
- Command's ID ( 1 byte )
- Command's control part ( 1 byte )
- Data field ( 15 byte )
- Check ( 1 byte )

For example the complete package for switching the light on is *"A1080100FFFFFF59"*
So far everything is clear to me. The only thing I struggle with is the last byte or how it is called in the document: *"Check"*.
The document just says: *"The instruction of check code: check code=(0 - expect the sum of byte in whole byte)"*.
In the example above *"59"* would be the checksum. But no matter how I try to calculate it I won't get to *"59"*.

I found the nice little helper

```
public extension Data {
    public func checkSum() -> Int {
        return self.map { Int($0) }.reduce(0, +) & 0xff
    } 
}
```

But I don't get the right *"checks"* for any command.

Maybe someone has an idea how this is calculated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`256 - [your checksum algorithm]` returns `0x59`, so maybe that's it:

```
var data = Data([0xA1, 0x08, 0x01, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF])

extension Data {
    var checksum: Int {
        return self.map { Int($0) }.reduce(0, +) & 0xff
    }
}

let result = 256 - data.checksum
"0x\(String(result, radix: 16))" // "0x59"
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks very much.

Comment: Yes, the document says "0 - expect the sum of byte in whole byte".  In 8 bit unsigned  bit arithmetic, `0 &- x` is the same as `256 &- x` As you actually need a `UInt8` you can simplify the checksum calculation like this: `return 0 &-  self.reduce(0, &+)`