# How to get checksum in byte [UInt8] array in swift 4?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have byte array and I need get checksum:

```
let bytes : [UInt8] = [0xC4, 0x03, 0x01, 0x09, 0x03]
```

I try this code but it did not help me:

```
let result = 256 - dataByte.checksum
extension Data {
 var checksum: Int {
    return self.map { Int($0) }.reduce(0, +) & 0xff
 }
}
```

My friend who is the developer try to get checksum on Kotlin, like this:

```
var checksum = 0
    for (i in 0..lastIndex) {
        checksum = checksum xor this[i].toInt()
    }
    return checksum
```

And he got this result 0x0B and I need the same result only on swift 4.

Comment: For a starter, XOR  is `^`, not `+`.

Comment: But the XOR of all bytes in [0xC4, 0x03, 0x01, 0x09, 0x03] is 0xCC – it is unclear to me how the result 0x0B should be obtained.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46645722/swift-checksum-of-bytes)?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you `XOR` all the values in your array:

```
let bytes: [UInt8] = [0xC4, 0x03, 0x01, 0x09, 0x03]
let checksum = bytes.reduce(0, ^)
print(checksum) // 204, which equals 0xCC
```

As mentioned by Martin R, the result is 0xCC, and not 0x0B.

Comment: There's no need for `& 0xFF` in this case. In the original code, that was to mask off the overflow from `+`, but using `^` the output cannot be larger than the input.